# C++ error C2065: 'Value' : undeclared identifier -Newbe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, accessor

Hi I am new to Visual Studio 2010
When I try build my code it tells me:

> count.cpp(18): error C2065: 'Value' : undeclared identifier

That is my count.cpp code giving out the error:

```
 #include "StdAfx.h"
 #include "count.h"


 count::count(void):  Value(0), ResetValue(0){} //constructor

 count::~count(void){} //destructor

 int GetValue(){return Value;} //Accessor to get value by another class
```

Here is my count.h code:

```
 #pragma once
 class count
 {
 public:
    count(void);
    virtual ~count(void);
    int GetValue();
 private:
     int Value;
    int ResetValue;
 };
```

It's a count object that's going to be used by a  countWindow object.
So I want an "GetValue" accessor and make use of a pointer in my countWindow dialog window.

Is the variable Value not declared and initiated on the line 12 when I actually make use of the constructor?
Or is it not link to the declaration in the count.h file?

Because if I create another void function to just do a Value++, Visual studio seems fine with.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetValue is being declared as a global not a member of the count class.  Preface the GetValue declaration with count::

```
int count::GetValue(){return Value;} //Accessor to get value by another class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count::GetValue(){return Value;} //Accessor to get value by another class
```

Note the count::